# Reading multiple files and then separating strings

Tags: java

I've read multiple files and reading tokens using `StringTokenizer`, but my problem is it reads "Geneliad'souza" as the same, but I want it as "geneliad" and "souza" as separate words. Could you please explain the code for this logic?

A word starts with a letter (A-Z or a-z) and continues until a non-letter (or EOF) is encountered.

A snippet from my code :

```
String line = fileReader.nextLine();
String word = null;

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);

while (st.hasMoreTokens()) { // while2 starts
    word = st.nextToken().toLowerCase();
    ...
```

Comment: I tried using regex in JAVA but this couldnt work

Comment: @TheLostMind : noo the only condition that is a word starts with a letter (A-Z or a-z) and continues until a non-letter (or EOF) is encountered

Comment: use delim in StringTokenizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String line = fileReader.nextLine();
String[] tokens = line.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
for(String token : tokens) {
  System.out.println(token);
}
```

Using `StringTokenizer` is quite messy and never preferred for complex splits but this may give you a general idea of how to use it.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," !?,.@#$%&_-*^/\"'`\\t\\n\\");
```

Comment: Also here: add a '+' at the end of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`StringTokenizer` is not supposed (thanks, [laune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107876/laune)) to be used with more than one `String` as delimiter, but you want it to be used with some variants.
Also, as [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) says, "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons", so you should avoid it's using in the code and use this way:

```
String[] words = line.split("[^a-zA-Z]+");
```

Here the regular expression will match just any characters (sequence of characters), except for the letters.

Comment: The second argument of StringTokenizer is *not* a regular expression. And the second proposal should have a + in the pattern.

Comment: @laune yep, you're right. Will fix the answer soon.

Comment: @laune - removed my comment asking the OP to try the same.. Didn't know what exactly he wants :P. Check his comment.

Comment: @TheLostMind With `split` we're back to regex anyway, although in a gentle form ;-) (I removed my above comment as well.)